# How to edit page not found template Yii2?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to edit Not Found (#404) template in advanced template Yii2 with custom layout and text?

html message:

```
<div class="site-error">
    <h1>Not Found (#404)</h1>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Page not found.    </div>
    <p>
        The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
    </p>
    <p>
        Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? You can't find this file?

Comment: I have found `throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'Page not found.'));` in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php, but I want to create custom template in frontend/ if it's possible

Comment: Does this file (`frontend/views/site/error.php`) exist in your application?

Comment: It was erased, but I got it, thank you